# How to reload icons which are already registered as previews

Tags: python, interface

I try to understand this Blender Example:
[Blender Docs: Preview](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.previews.html)

```
import bpy

class PreviewsExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Previews Example Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

        row = layout.row()
        my_icon = pcoll["my_icon"]
        row.operator("render.render", icon_value=my_icon.icon_id)

        # my_icon.icon_id can be used in any UI function that accepts
        # icon_value # try also setting text=""
        # to get an icon only operator button

# We can store multiple preview collections here,
# however in this example we only store "main"
preview_collections = {}

def register():

    # Note that preview collections returned by bpy.utils.previews
    # are regular py objects - you can use them to store custom data.
    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    # path to the folder where the icon is
    # the path is calculated relative to this py file inside the addon folder
    my_icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")

    # load a preview thumbnail of a file and store in the previews collection
    pcoll.load("my_icon", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "icon-image.png"), 'IMAGE')

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)

def unregister():

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

What I don't understand is: how can I reload the icons from a custom function after they are registered and drawn?
I don't understand how I can reference and change them later.
Can someone shed some light on this?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Okay, so as it seems, there is no way to reload the images in this example.
At least, in this example one has an ID for the images so the following reference works:

```
pcoll = preview_collections["main"] 
layout.label(text=r"",icon_value=pcoll["SomeFile.png"].icon_id)
```

There is another example in the Blender Templates: ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py

This produces a dynamic list of images but there is no ID so I can't reference it as above.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import bpy


def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):
    """EnumProperty callback"""
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager
    directory = wm.my_previews_dir

    # Get the preview collection (defined in register func).
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the directory for png files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(".png"):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # generates a thumbnail preview for a file.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
            if not icon:
                thumb = pcoll.load(name, filepath, 'IMAGE')
            else:
                thumb = pcoll[name]
            enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


class PreviewsExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Previews Example Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(wm, "my_previews_dir")

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(wm, "my_previews")
preview_collections = {}


def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        EnumProperty,
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default=""
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
        items=enum_previews_from_directory_items,
    )
preview_collections = {}


def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        EnumProperty,
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default=""
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
        items=enum_previews_from_directory_items,
    )
```

The only reference to the actual image in this code is in the panel, like here:

```
row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews")
```

This is the actually selected image. The following code tells me it's number in the list:

```
bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan']['my_previews']
```

But how do I reference the whole list?

How do I list the newest (eventually reloaded) state of this list and how can I search for some content in it?

Answer (score 0):

My intention was to create icons in my interface with an initial status and then change the icons based on some functions.
Reloading the icons with the same key throws a "key already exists" error and it is not possible to change the value (Path & File Name) of that key.
So at last the solution was to have a second function (after the initial loading of the icons) which can be called and in that function one has to first close the preview collection (which removes it's content) and then reload the icons.

I think it makes sense to have two sets of icons: one set for fixed icons and another one for the dynamic icons.

I wrote a quick example which works fine for me:

```
import bpy
from bpy.utils import previews
 
icons = previews.new()

icons.load(
    name='Test_Icon',
    path='/_DATA/Temp/Icon1.png',
    path_type='IMAGE'
)

def Load_Icon_F():
    icons.clear()
    icons.load(
        name='Test_Icon',
        path='/_DATA/Temp/Icon2.png',
        path_type='IMAGE',
        force_reload=True
    )

class LOAD_OT_Icon(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Load Icon Operator"""
    bl_idname = "load.icon"
    bl_label = "Load Icon Operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            Load_Icon_F()
        except Exception as exc:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, 'Error loading Icons. ')
        return {"FINISHED"}

class TEST_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_category = "Icon_TEST"
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PT_panel'
    bl_label = 'TEST'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator(
            operator='load.icon',
            text='Reload Icons',
            icon_value=icons['Test_Icon'].icon_id
        )      
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LOAD_OT_Icon)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_PT_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LOAD_OT_Icon)
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(icons)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I just realized that my code only works once. :-(
Pressing the button a second time, gets an error and the error is caused by icons.close().
I don't understand why it works once but not a second time. It is so hard to work with these previews or I am too dumb to understand them. Does anyone have an idea why the close() function is not working the second time? (I reload the preview right after the close() so it's not empty.)

Comment: I replaced close() with clear() and then it works. Looks like close() get's rid of the preview but then I still don't understand why I was able to close() it the first time and then load() in to the closed preview the new icon. This just don't make any sense to me.